# Sum rows based on cell value and then delete all duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I have an Excel Sheet where some rows may contain the same data as other rows. I need a macro to sum all the values in that column and delete all the duplicates rows, except for the first one, which contains the sum of the rest.

[image]

I have tried multiple versions of code and the code that produces the results closest to what I need looks like this, but this code contains one problem is: infinite loop.

```
Sub delet()
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim y As Worksheet
    Dim j As Double
    Dim k As Double

    Set y = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    b = y.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To b
        For k = j + 1 To b
            If Cells(j, 2).Value = Cells(k, 2).Value Then
                Cells(j, 3).Value = (Cells(j, 3).Value + Cells(k, 3).Value)
                Rows(k).EntireRow.Delete
                k = k - 1
            ElseIf Cells(j, 2).Value <> Cells(k, 2).Value Then
                k = k
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: After the first duplicate, you set `k = k-1`, doesn't that mean that j=k for the next loop? And what is the point of `k = k`?

Comment: if two rows have the same value the code will delete the last row so that's why I set  `K=K-1`                                                                                                                                         I must to delete `K=K`

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend getting the data in an array and then do the relevant operation. This is a small range and it may not affect the performance but for a larger dataset it will matter.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim MyAr As Variant, outputAr As Variant
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim itm As Variant
    Dim totQty As Double
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find last row of col A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Get those value in an array
        MyAr = .Range("A2:C" & lRow).Value2
        
        '~~> Get unique collection of Fam.
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            If Len(Trim(MyAr(i, 2))) <> 0 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                col.Add MyAr(i, 2), CStr(MyAr(i, 2))
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next i
        
        '~~> Prepare array for output
        ReDim outputAr(1 To col.Count, 1 To 3)
        
        i = 1
        
        For Each itm In col
            '~~> Get Product
            For j = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
                If MyAr(i, 2) = itm Then
                    outputAr(i, 1) = MyAr(i, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            
            '~~> Fam.
            outputAr(i, 2) = itm
            
            totQty = 0
            
            '~~> Qty
            For j = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
                If MyAr(j, 2) = itm Then
                    totQty = totQty + Val(MyAr(j, 3))
                End If
            Next j
            
            outputAr(i, 3) = totQty
            
            i = i + 1
        Next itm
        
        '~~> Copy headers
        .Range("A1:C1").Copy .Range("G1")
        '~~> Write array to relevant range
        .Range("G2").Resize(UBound(outputAr), 3).Value = outputAr
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Yes it's working , that's exactly what I'm looking for , Thank you @Siddarth_Rout

Answer (score 1):

If VBA isn't essential and you've got 365:

In cell `G2` enter the formula `=UNIQUE(A2:B11)`
In cell `I2` enter the formula `=SUMIFS(C2:C11,A2:A11,INDEX(G2#,,1),B2:B11,INDEX(G2#,,2))`

Comment: unfortunately, I have to use VBA, thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Remove Duplicates with Sum

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- Note that if you choose the same worksheets and `"A1"`, you will overwrite.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub removeDupesSum()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "G1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = wb.Worksheets(sName).Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value
    
    ' Write unique values from Data Array to Unique Sum Dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim arr As Variant: ReDim arr(2 To UBound(Data, 1)) ' for first column
    Dim n As Long: n = 1
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If dict.Exists(Data(i, 2)) Then
            dict(Data(i, 2)) = dict(Data(i, 2)) + Data(i, 3)
        Else
            n = n + 1
            arr(n) = Data(i, 1)
            dict(Data(i, 2)) = Data(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i
    
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To dict.Count + 1, 1 To 3)
    ' Write headers.
    For i = 1 To 3
        Result(1, i) = Data(1, i)
    Next i
    Erase Data
    ' Write 'body'.
    Dim Key As Variant
    i = 1
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        i = i + 1
        Result(i, 1) = arr(i)
        Result(i, 2) = Key
        Result(i, 3) = dict(Key)
    Next Key
    
    ' Write values from Result Array to Destination Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst).Resize(, 3)
        .Resize(i).Value = Result
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - i + 1).Offset(i).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am a beginner in VBA,and my knowledge in array and dictionary object is limited but your answer really helped me thank you so much